# Check if SAP Content Server is running

Tags: content-management-system, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, netweaver

I'm trying to install **SAP Content Server 6.40** onto a Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine.

I've read through several installation manuals and how-tos on the web. But can't seem to get it running.

The installation SAP is pretty straightforward. You have to choose SAP NetWeaver 7 element in the installation packages tree, then Standalone Engines -> Content Server -> content Server and or Cache Server. From thereon there you follow the instructions and the installation completes successfully.

The next step to follow is to check whether the server is running by using this request:

```
http:\\<servername>:1090\ContentServer\ContentServer.dll?serverInfo
```

The Content Server version should be displayed, but it is **not**.

I tried it with the actual domain, with localhost and the loopback address(es) (127.0.0.[n]) from within the VM.

Before the installation I did set up the IIS (HTTP server). I tried it with configuring the running IIS (i.e., creating a site and pointing it to the Content Server directory - although it is apparently not needed as per the manuals I've read) and without.

---

**QUESTION**

What could be the cause of the issue I'm facing? Why are the Content Server DLLs not reacting to access per HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to *allow* the `ContentServer.dll` to be executed.
To do so visit the **ISAPI and CGI Restrictions**, there you have to
add the aforementioned `dll`.

You have to install certain Role Services for IIS first (in Application Development).